# What will be the faster in Java: DB2 INSERT/SELECT or File Write/Read

Tags: java, multithreading, db2

While working on a application, on parsing a large number of text files (e.g. 4000 files); found time delay in storing/reading the parsed data into DB2 using JDBC as INSERT/SELECT Prepared Statements. (FYI: Using a separate thread to parse the data, then pased the date to another thread for saving into DB2).

**Could I use a File Write/Read mechanism to parse data, instead of DB2 interaction? Will it be faster than?**

> If File handling will be faster, then which mechanism need to be use:
>   Simple File write/Read or Object Write/Read?

Comment: "It depends". There is the SQL "overhead", **but it - the RDBMS - does something entirely different**. Databases are about information.

Comment: But using a database gives advantages that files don't give. Performance should not be the only criteria. With databases, later access and queries are simpler...

Comment: @pst What is the DB2 "overhead"? Could you give a light on this please.

Comment: How big are the files?  DB2 tends to have file-load utilities, which would pretty much solve this _for_ you.  And what do you mean File Write/Read - are you talking about, say, an iSeries?  If so, any sort of batched SQL statements will far outpace single-record programs

Comment: I suggest if you got the necessary answer, please accept the answer and close the question..

Answer (score 2):

Simple file read/write should be faster if used properly, i.e. if data is transferred in large chunks.

Also, consider using [memory-mapped files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html).

Comment: But memory-mapped file may have out of memory issue, if no of files to be processed increased.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on what scope of data you want to read/write. Reading a huge file has its own overhead. If source is a small file you can obviously read it quickly since parsing overhead will be low. But if file consists of complex structure , RDBMS or Database might be a feasible option.

Another option is you might want to look into Automicity,consistancy, isolation and durability (ACID) for the data you want to read and write.

Comment: What is it ? Automicity,consistancy, isolation and durability (ACID) ?

Comment: @Kishore - As usual, there's a [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

Comment: When working with data, we need to consider in what way the data will be used. Just speed would not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using DB2 LOAD from Java. The insertion will be very fast, and you could use a cursor for a select, or insert from a file.

However, inserting / loading data into a database is completly different to write to a file. What do you want to do?